# How to remove particular value into NSMutableArray using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am facing some empty values adding into NSMutableArray issue. I need to remove that one before loading on tableview because Its adding empty row on table.

Into my array (like: "") this type of empty quotes adding. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a category on `NSMutableArray`, and validate the string while adding it to array

your implementation should look like this,

```
#import "NSMutableArray+Validation.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Validation)

- (void)addObjectIfItsValidString:(id)anObject
{
    if (anObject && [anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ((NSString *)anObject).length > 0) {
        [self addObject:anObject];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray already has built-in `removeObjectIdenticalTo` method that removes **all** occurrences of specific object, so you can just do the following:

```
[array removeObjectIdenticalTo:@""]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[anArray removeObjectAtIndex: index];
[anArray removeObject: item];
[anArray removeLastObject];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this it might help you.

```
for (int i=0;i<array.count;i++) {
        NSString *string = array[i];
        if(string.length==0||[string isEqualToString:@""]){
            [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int index = [arr indexOfObject:@""];
 [arr removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: Can you expand on this answer at all? Good answers explain what the problem is and how to fix it rather than simply supplying a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:

NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array];
[set removeObject:@""];
NSArray *result =[set allObjects];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

and If you have array of dictionary so you can try this:

```
NSArray* keysToGo = [myDictionary allKeysForObject: @""];
[myDictionary removeObjectsForKeys: keysToGo];
```